# How to create a raster of equidistant points with distance in meters using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, point, distance, coordinates

I need a set of equidistant points (like a raster) each in a 1km distance to the next over a certain area, in my case Germany. I know the feature "regular points" in QGIS where I can do just that but the distance you can enter there is not in meters but in coordinates or something.

I tried it in WGS 84 as well as in EPSG:31467 (Gauss-Kruger, common in Germany) which is supposed to be in meters but the results seem to be the same. I just can't find a way to set a certain distance in meters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your **project** CRS is set to EPSG:31467, and you have a vector layer in the same CRS for the border extent, the output layer of `regular points` will have the same CRS.

Enter a distance of 1000 to get points in 1km distance.

Make sure **NOT** to use any WGS84 layers which has degrees as units.

Comment: Somehow that doesn't work for me - I end up having a single point on the upper left corner because the distance of 1000 seems to be too big. Do you know another CRS that works with meters and delivers good quality distances in Germany?

Comment: If you rightclick on the point layer, `Set CRS for Layer`, is EPSG:31467 selected or EPSG:4326? The second would be wrong. What is the extent of the border layer?

Comment: It is EPSG:31467. The border layer is Hesse, a state of Germany. I also set it's CRS to EPSG:31467.

Comment: When you rightclick on the border layer, Properties -> Metadata tab will report the extent of the layer. If it is below 15/55, the data is in degrees, not meters.

Comment: It says: xMin,yMin 7.78455;49.4041 : xMax,yMax 10.2371;51.6572 so I guess the data is in degrees. Does that mean I have to find another border layer with data in meters?

Comment: So you have to `Set CRS for layer` back to EPSG:4326, then `Save As ...` the layer under another name using EPSG:31467. With that new border file, the points will appear as expected.

Comment: Wow, now it actually worked! Many thanks for your help and patience!